# Out of range problem in my linearsearch method

Tags: c#, arrays, linear-search

So now I've been adding some code to my program.

Method LinearSearch:

```
static int LinearSearch(City[] cities, int key)
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < cities.Length; i++)
    {      
        if (cities[i].temp == key)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
```

}
and then..

```
Console.Write("enter temperature to search for:");
string str = Console.ReadLine();
int key = Convert.ToInt32(str);

int index = LinearSearch(cities, key);


    if (index == -1)
        Console.WriteLine($"Couldn't find any city with temperature {key}");
    else   
        Console.WriteLine($"You searched for {key}");
        Console.WriteLine($"INDEX: {index}\t CITY: {cities[index].name} =\t TEMP: {cities[index].temp}");
```

When I then search for a value that's not in the array I first getting my answer: "Couldn't find any city with temperature {key}".

but then I get this messenge:

> Unhandled exception. System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was
> outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: two lines after `else` should be wrapped within `{` and `}`

Comment: Unlike Python, indenting in C# is just to make things pretty and means absolutely nothing in terms of grouping blocks of code together.

Comment: Of course it has to be wrapped within { }. thank you.